# WFS filter query does not return points (selected from polygon)

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

I'm a newbie to OpenLayers (and JavaScript for that matter) and hoping you can offer some advice. I have been referring to examples http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html and http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Select-WFS-Features-using-intersect-of-polygon-td4467419.html but have not had any luck getting any features returned from a spatial filter (a user-drawn polygon). The server response is as follows, and I'm not sure what it means:

```
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>
        org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 294;
        Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. 
        Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.
    </ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
```

Anyway, my code is below. Please let me know if there is something I am missing.

```
var wfsPIF = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("PIFs", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: "http://new-raptor.weatherfusion.com/geoserver/wf_data/wfs", 
        featureType: "erie_pif_wfs",
        featurePrefix:"",
        geometryName: "geom"
    }),
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
       pointRadius: 2,
       fillColor: "red"
    })
}); 
map.addLayer(wfsPIF);


var drawControl, polygonLayer;

polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Query Polygon");
map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
drawControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);
map.addControl(drawControl);
drawControl.activate();

polygonLayer.events.on({
    featureadded: function(event) {
        var geometry = event.feature.geometry;
        wfsPIF.filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.WITHIN,
            value: event.feature.geometry
        });
        wfsPIF.refresh({force: true});
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `http://new-raptor.weatherfusion.com/geoserver/wf_data/wfs` is refusing access (GetCapabilities request), do you have direct access, or do you have access if you provide some security token(s)?